# Double Pipe Character in emacs lisp regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am trying to understand this regexp 
I'm having a hard time understanding this pattern:

```
\\(\\||.+?\\)
```

What does the or do at the beginning? Why two pipe characters?

It's a part of a regexp designed to match anything enclosed in brackets (for cloze deletion) from Paul Sexton's org-drill.

```
"\\(\\[[[:cntrl:][:graph:][:space:]]*?\\)\\(\\||.+?\\)\\(\\]\\)"
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Joscha

Answer (score 3):

The first pipe character is escaped, and so it becomes the regular expression character for alternation.  The second pipe character is not escaped, so it represents a literal pipe character in the text being matched against.  As a whole, the first regexp you mention means "match either nothing, or a literal pipe character followed by one or more of any other characters, matched non-greedily."